# C++ identity function

Tags: c++, functional-programming, template, c++14, type-safety

I've implemented an `identity` function (well, actually a functor `struct`) in C++. The goal is that *every occurrence of an expression `expr` in the code can be substituted by `identity(expr)` without changing the semantics of the program at all*.

I make it a `struct` with a templated `operator()` instead of simply a function template because this enables us to pass `identity` as an argument to other functions (say `std::transform`) without needing to specify the type (e.g., `identity<std::pair<std::vector<int>::const_iterator, std::vector<double>::const_iterator>>`).

The code is written in C++14.

```
#include <utility>

static constexpr struct identity_t {
    template<typename T>
    constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(T&& t) const noexcept
    {
        return std::forward<T>(t);
    }
} identity{};
```

Usage:

```
int x = 42;
identity(x) = 24;

constexpr int size = 123;
int arr[identity(size)] = {};

vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3, 4}, v2;
v2.reserve(v1.size());
transform(v1.cbegin(), v1.cend(),
          back_inserter(v2),
          identity);

template<typename T>
class my_container {
public:
    template<typename F>
    auto flat_map(F&& f) const { ... }

    auto flatten() const { return flat_map(identity); }

    ...
};
```

Since `identity(expr)` is nothing more than a cast, performance should not be a problem. I'm concerned whether there are cases in which this implementation fails to keep the program's behavior unchanged. If there are, how can I fix the implementation?

**EDIT:** I changed "a variable `x`" in the first paragraph to "an expression `expr`". The latter is more accurate.

Comment: Those `...`'s in your code suggest that there is more to your implementation, which you need to include.  Right now this question is off topic as it is basically stub code.

Comment: @syb0rg No, the `...` is not part of my implementation. That's part of the examples which is not relevant to the discussion. The full implementation is in the first code block.

Comment: Does it work as intended even without the examples (those cut away with the `...`)?

Comment: @Mast I'm not exactly sure what you mean; `identity` itself does work.

Comment: @syb0rg I'm new to Code Review, so I don't know if I should remove incomplete examples. Please let me know if I should so I can edit the post accordingly.

Comment: @ZizhengTai I think they're fine as is, as long as the code you're looking to have reviewed is complete and works as intended.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review :-) Feel free to take a look at the [How to Ask - FAQ](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915) to see what goes and what doesn't here. We hope to see you around some more.

Comment: I think if you've got an overloaded function or function template which you pass to a function pointer argument, you won't be able to insert `identity`. However that's a limitation of the language that cannot be avoided.

Comment: @celtschk True, never thought about that. I guess we'll have to assign the function to a typed function pointer first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, that looks like a straightforward use of perfect forwarding in the parameter (`T&&`, `std::forward<T>`) and in the return type (`decltype(auto)`). So yep, you've got it.

There are plenty of places in C++ where `x` and `identity(x)` don't do the same thing, either because `x` is a name as well as an expression, or because `x` is a construct that *looks* like an expression but technically is not one. (Personally, I consider almost all of these places to be mistakes in the design of C++.) Here are the ones I can think of.

Replacing `identity(x)` with `x` in all of the following examples changes the behavior of the code sample.

---

As mentioned in the comments on the question, the name of a function template can deduce what kind of function pointer to decay to:

```
template<class T> void f(T) {}
void (*fp)(int) = identity(f);
```

---

The name of a local variable gets copy elision (a.k.a. Named Return Value Optimization, or NRVO):

```
struct S {
    S() {}
    S(const S&) { puts("copy"); }
    S(S&&) { puts("move"); }
};
S f() {
    S s;
    return identity(s);
}
int main() { f(); }
```

---

The name of a local variable is treated as an rvalue in the context of `return`:

```
struct S {
    S() {}
    S(const S&) { puts("copy"); }
    S(S&&) { puts("move"); }
};
std::any f() {
    S s;
    return identity(s);
}
int main() { f(); }
```

---

Lifetime extension applies to temporaries whose construction is "visible" in some sense that is extremely subtle when I start thinking hard about it. Interposing the call to `identity` disables lifetime extension.

```
struct S {
    S() { puts("ctor"); }
    S(const S&) = delete;
    S(S&&) = delete;
    ~S() { puts("dtor"); }
};
int main() {
    const S& x = identity(S());
    puts("done");
}
```

---

Braced initializers and string literals *look* like expressions, but in the context of an initializer, they're special cases:

```
const char x[] = identity("hello");
int y = identity({5});
```

---

Now, I can't imagine how you'd use `identity` in your codebase where any of these quirks might matter; but then, I don't quite see how you plan to use `identity` at all. Your only fleshed-out example is just using `std::transform(..., identity)` as a verbose way of writing `std::copy(...)`, which doesn't seem very useful.