# Haskell-like function composition function

Tags: c++, haskell, functional-programming, template-meta-programming, type-safety

Much like [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/226073/function-composition-in-c) I'm attempting to write in C++ something which can resemble Haskell's `(.)` function as much as possible, which is basically Chapter 1's second exercise from [Bartosz Milewski's Category Theory for Programmers](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/11/04/category-the-essence-of-composition/).

[This similar question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134627/c-identity-function) about writing the *identity* function served as a reference too.

[This answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42799251/5825294) reassured me that `decltype` used on lambdas' `auto` parameters is equivalent to `decltype` used on template parameters.

And this is what I came up with:

```cpp
static constexpr struct compose_t {
    template <typename F, typename G>
    constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(F&& f, G&& g) const noexcept {
        return [&f,&g](auto&& x){
            return f(g(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)));
        };
    }
} compose;
```

Some thoughts:

- `operator()` takes `f` and `g` by reference, and the returned lambda captures them by reference; and I made this choice thinking it should make passing non-stateless callables cheaper, but [I'm not sure I made the right choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196345/passing-functor-object-by-value-vs-by-reference-c).  Another reference is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522198/5825294).
- Since I'm passing them by reference, I had to choose between `const&` and `&&`, and I've basically chosen randomly.
- I've not concerned myself with variadics, as I wanted a *binary* function composition "operator", in line with Haskell's `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`.
- I cannot compose `compose` with something else, because it is binary, whereas the implementation implicitly assumes that `F` and `G` be unary. I guess making something like `compose(compose,compose)` (which is `(.).(.)` in Haskell) possible would be up to a partial application "facility".

This is a code where I tried to test it:

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <utility>

// ... the code from above

static constexpr struct changesign_t {
    template<typename T>
    constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(T&& t) const noexcept { return -t; };
} changesign;

int square(int x) { return x*x; }
int twice(int x) { return 2*x; }

int main() {
    assert(compose(square,twice)(3) == 36);
    assert(compose([](int x){ return x*x; },[](int x){ return 2*x; })(3) == 36);
    assert(compose(changesign, compose([](auto x){ return x*x; }, [](auto x){ return 2*x; }))(3) == -36);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to use a `struct compose_t` to wrap `operator()`, you can just move `operator()` out of it and rename it `compose()`:

```
template <typename F, typename G>
constexpr decltype(auto) compose(F&& f, G&& g) noexcept {
    return [&f,&g](auto&& x){
        return f(g(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)));
    };
}
```

Now it is also much closer to the code written in [this post you mentioned](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/226073/function-composition-in-c), except of course you are limited to composing only two unary functions.

Other than that, if you can live with the restrictions you have, I see nothing wrong with your implementation.